# $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = \int_{a}^{b}A dx - \int_{a}^{b} B dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function.

Define
A = \begin{cases} f(x), & \mbox{if } f(x) \ge 0\mbox{} \\ 0, & \mbox{if } f(x) < 0\mbox{ } \end{cases}

Define B = \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } f(x) \ge 0\mbox{} \\ f(x), & \mbox{if } f(x) < 0\mbox{ } \end{cases}

How to prove that $A,B:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  are integrable and 
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) = \int_{a}^{b}A dx - \int_{a}^{b} B dx$$

Please help!

Comment: Do you know the definition of integrable? Do you know the definition of the value of an integral?

Comment: I know the definition of Riemann integrability, not sure about the value of integral(you mean the Riemann sums?).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P = (x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $[a,b]$ such that the difference of upper and lowers sums satisfies

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{k=1}^n[\sup_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x)](x_k - x_{k-1}) < \epsilon.$$

Note that

$$\sup_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}A(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}A(x) \leqslant \sup_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x) - \inf_{x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x).$$

Hence,

$$U(P,A)-L(P,A) < \epsilon,$$

and $A$ satisfies the Riemann criterion for integrability.

Make a similar argument for $B$.

Since $f(x) = A(x) - B(x)$ we have by the linearity of the Riemann integral

$$\int_a^bf(x) \, dx = \int_a^bA(x) \, dx - \int_a^bB(x) \, dx$$